# _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to write the object-oriented code in Python. Now I am stuck with an error:

> _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu"

I think the error lies in following line:

```
self.config(menu=menubar)
```

Following is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
class ImgComp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)        
        container = tk.Frame(self,width=320, height=209)        
        container.pack(side="top")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_propagate(False)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (PageOne):

            frame = F(container, self)
            #frame['bg'] = 'red'
            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(PageOne)        

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New")
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open")                    
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=filemenu)        
        self.config(menu=menubar)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)            

app = ImgComp()
app.mainloop()
```

Also I would like to inform, I have truncated the code as I was not allowed to post a bigger code by stackoverflow. Please help.

Comment: in your code `self` is a `Frame`, not `Tk` - try `controller.config(...)`

Comment: @furas . Doing what you told is now displaying menu on all the frames. How can I restrict to display the menu only on PageOne.

Comment: You could go `controller['menu'] = ''` in other frames.

Comment: @Nae I did that, it is removing menu from all the frames including PageOne.

Comment: @VrajeshDoshi I meant as in, what furas suggests in PageOne, and what I suggest in all pages you don't want menu with. As in: use `controller['menu'] = menubar` if you want menu with that page and `controller['menu'] = ''` if you don't want menu with that page, for each page.

Comment: @Nae, I did the same what you are expecting, i.e. in PageOne I have controller.config(menu=menubar) and in other frames I have entered controller['menu'] = ' '. Even I tried writing in your way in PageOne, controller['menu'] = menubar

Comment: @VrajeshDoshi It's the way your pages are being shown. They're active at all times just not visible always. Which means you either have to call `menu` option modification along with frame showing or instead of creating all and showing once, create exactly what you'd want to show each time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161610/discussion-between-vrajesh-doshi-and-nae).

Comment: menu is not part of frame but window (`Tk`)  and all frames/pages are created at start so you have to show/hide menu in `show(). You can create variable `self.menubar` in every page - in one page it will have real menu and in others it will have empty string. And then in `show()` you can do `self["menu"] = frame.menubar`